# Fetch row based on group and having in influxDB

Tags: influxdb, influxql, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I'm new at influxDB and trying to solve a query. Where I need to fetch rows based on group by field3 columns and having should count less than 300. I've written it in SQL but not able to fetch any data from influxDB.

`select count(field1), count(field2) from powerandlevel where time > now()-10m group by field3 having count < 300`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this need to be in InfluxQL, or could use use a Flux query?

Comment: Yes, I need to work in influxQL